# Is there a specific term for letters that have the same appearance in both lower and upper case?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

There are letters that have the same "look" (excluding the size) in both lower and upper case.
`Cc`
`Oo`
`Pp`
`Ss`
`Vv`
`Ww`
`Xx`
`Zz`

In English, is there a specific term for these?

Comment: What does this have to do with English?

Comment: @tchrist I guess the word in English will be different to what the French call these letters. William, please read the tag descriptions. "Letter-writing" is about epistles, not characters.

Comment: @AndrewLeach This is still mostly an illusion caused by the choice of typeface. And it isn't even true if you look closely. And it's far less true in other hands even for the glyphs selected here. Consider for example true italics rather than roman, or unicameral uncials, blackletters like frakturs and texturas, or the countless script hands.  Even when their glyph forms look more or less isomorphic mathematically, close inspection always reveals that capital letters are different from small capitals are different from small letters. I recommend [graphicdesign.se]—or [math.se] for isomorphism.

Comment: I think that truly happens only with ***small caps*** fonts.

Comment: @williamfakespeare I trust you'll find [this sonnet familiar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0lF0.png). Do all those various instances of *S/s* and *W/w* &c have “the same look” for your question’s purposes? They do not look that way to me, but you might be seeing things differently.